# Pass UIImage to RCTRootView

Tags: ios, react-native, uiimage

I'm working on a hybrid ios native/react-native project.

Let's say I have an instance of `UIImage` at some point in my app.
I need to display this image in my react-native component. I create an `RCTRootView` like this:

```
  RCTRootView *rootView = [[RCTRootView alloc] initWithBundleURL:jsCodeLocation
                                                  moduleName:@"SomeScreen"
                                           initialProperties:someParameters
                                               launchOptions:launchOptions];
```

What do I do next?
Facebook describes how to use the `<Image>` component with uri, addressing an image in local file system or in Web. But I don't want to download it twice (also I don't want to reimplement authentication in react-native).

Is there any way to pass already existing `UIImage` to react-native component?

Answer (score 1):

I know the code in OP's question is in Obj-C but I was working on this using Java (and this question is already 2 years old). If you're using Obj-C translate this code from Swift to Obj-C as it should work.

What I did to send image data from my Native (Swift) application to my RN app was:

I sent the image as a base 64 encoded String by doing this:

```swift
//Add more images as needed
let images = [UIImage(named: "myImage")?.pngData()?.base64EncodedString()]
let props: [String : [String?]] = [
    "images": images //Remember this key
]
let rootView = RCTRootView(
    bundleURL: jsCodeLocation,
    moduleName: "RNHelloWorld",
    initialProperties: props,
    launchOptions: nil
)
```

Then, on your RN class do this:

```
export default class MyClass extends React.Component {
    renderImage(encodedImage) {
        //You need to manually specify widht and height
        //And decode your image as a base 64 image
        return <Image style={width: 50, height: 50} source={{uri: `data:image/png;base64,${encodedImage}`}} />
    }
    render() {
        //Use the same name as in your props key in Swift
        return <View>{this.props.images.map(this.renderImage}</View>
    }
}
```

Then, you're good to go.